# AVPlayer HLS live stream falls behind

Tags: ios, avplayer, http-live-streaming

I'm working on AVPlayer + HLS with live stream,
Sometimes, the video will fall behind and I need all clients to be in-sync with the stream. 
How do we know when this happens? I'd want to re-sync it when it falls behind.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may use your player API to analyze playback statistics and events like rebuffering.

Answer (score 0):

To do so you will need to use the method [seekToTime](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer/1385953-seektotime) and pass the player [current time](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer/1390404-currenttime) with the value of the new buffered time.